# Couldn't they have just shutdown the power to the Royal Mint?

Tags: money-heist

I finished watching Money Heist and it is an epic of a show. But I have had this question nagging in the initial 2 seasons.

Earlier, Raquel suggests no food, no water and Prieto counters with, "They're not going to give up because they didn't get their dessert" or something along those lines.

But, after knowing what the real motive of the heist was: To print their own money, couldn't they have just cut off the power supply?

1. The negotiations can still happen because it is analog.
2. Professor wouldn't have the resources to generate that amount of electricity.
3. Professor would have been blind due to no CCTV feeds.
4. Electrical tools wouldn't have worked.

Is there an explanation for this that I might have missed?

Answer (score 1):

The question arising from your perspective is absolutely correct. But I would like to mention some things which might clear your doubts to some extent.

1. What matters at the time of the *heist* was not the electricity cut.  The safety of the hostages was more important to them. *(Don't forget even the police tried to come inside the mint due to the exact locations of the robbers in which electricity was needed)*
2. Without electricity they wouldn't have been able to broadcast the proof of each hostage which was shown in later episodes.
3. Not to forget the most important hostage named *Alison Parker*, who was a high profile hostage, was also there. So the risk factor remains high if they wouldn't be able to communicate as Colonel *Prieto* was only concerned about her life.

I guess there might be some other useful points. Wait and watch.